# How to clear all applied filters in Mui React DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is a component called TableContainer.js it shows the headers of tables. It has 6 buttons. The buttons should be able to do things to the grid it contains eg the first button is 'clear filters'. How can I clear all applied filters to the MUI Datagrid?

[image]

**TableContainer.js**

```
export default function TableContainer({ title, sx, table, columns, children, clearFilter }) {



    return (
        <Box sx={{ height: '100%', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid gray', boxShadow: '0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)', overflow: 'hidden', ...sx }} >
            <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" sx={{ backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white', padding: '10px' }} >
                <Box  >{title} </Box>
                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row"  >
                    <Box  > <Iconify icon="codicon:filter-filled" sx={{}} onClick={clearFilter}/>X</Box>
                    <Box  > <Iconify icon="charm:chevrons-up-down" sx={{}} />X</Box>
                    <Box  > <Iconify icon="gridicons:not-visible" sx={{}} />13</Box>
                    <Box  >  <Iconify icon="bxs:lock" sx={{}} />5</Box>
                    <Box  > <Iconify icon="fluent:arrow-sort-20-filled" sx={{}} /></Box>
                    <Box  > <Iconify icon="file-icons:microsoft-excel" sx={{}} /></Box>
                </Stack>
            </Stack>
            <Box sx={{ height: 'calc(100% - 44px)' }}>
                {children}
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

**MyDataGrid.js**

```
<TableContainer title='My Datagrid'>
        <DataGridPro
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pagination={false}
          components={{
            LoadingOverlay,
          }}
          selectionModel={selectionModel}
          onSelectionModelChange={setSelectionModel}
        />
      </TableContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here just you need to set `<DataGridPro/>` key like

```
export default function TableContainer({
  title,
  sx,
  table,
  columns,
  children,
  clearFilter,
}) {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: "100%",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        border: "1px solid gray",
        boxShadow:
          "0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)",
        overflow: "hidden",
        ...sx,
      }}
    >
      <Stack
        spacing={2}
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="space-between"
        sx={{ backgroundColor: "black", color: "white", padding: "10px" }}
      >
        <Box>{title} </Box>
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
          <Box>
            {" "}
            <Iconify
              icon="codicon:filter-filled"
              sx={{}}
              onClick={clearFilter}
            />
            X
          </Box>
          <Box>
            {" "}
            <Iconify icon="charm:chevrons-up-down" sx={{}} />X
          </Box>
          <Box>
            {" "}
            <Iconify icon="gridicons:not-visible" sx={{}} />
            13
          </Box>
          <Box>
            {" "}
            <Iconify icon="bxs:lock" sx={{}} />5
          </Box>
          <Box>
            {" "}
            <Iconify icon="fluent:arrow-sort-20-filled" sx={{}} />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            {" "}
            <Iconify icon="file-icons:microsoft-excel" sx={{}} />
          </Box>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
      <Box sx={{ height: "calc(100% - 44px)" }}>{children}</Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

here create one state to set the index key

`MyDataGrid.js`

```
const [muiTableKey, setMuiTableKey] = React.useState(0);

<TableContainer
  title="My Datagrid"
  clearFilter={() => setMuiTableKey(muiTableKey + 1)}
>
  <DataGridPro
    key={muiTableKey}
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pagination={false}
    components={{ LoadingOverlay }}
    selectionModel={selectionModel}
    onSelectionModelChange={setSelectionModel}
  />
</TableContainer>
```

Comment: There are multiple filtering on the columns of the Datagrid. With this index key, how can I clear the applied filter to Datagrid?

Comment: it's clear all filters you can find out demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-brahmagupta-o8wnn?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Yes. I missed the key in DataGrid

Comment: Can I pass the reference of the grid to TableContainer component and do the same on TableContainer?

Comment: yes u can also pass ref and do same

Comment: How? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Without rerendering the grid can we do the same by using Datagrid API?

Comment: need to check @sjMalik

Comment: without rerendering grid, we can use filterModel prop. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3jwkg?file=/demo.js. But not able to figure out how can I do same in TableContainer component by passing reference of the grid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246090/discussion-between-sjmalik-and-kanti-vekariya).

Answer (score 1):

For me, I added a state variable as a key to the DataGrid element and included an event listener (resetFilters()) to modify the variable (key), thereby triggering React to update and render the DataGrid element with the fresh data every time.

```
 const [muiTableKey, setMuiTableKey] = React.useState<any>(1);
..................................
  const resetFilters = async () => {
    setMuiTableKey(muiTableKey+1)
  }
..................
<DataGrid 
        rows={items}
        columns={columns}
        ... blah blah
        key={muiTableKey}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do the clear filter to write code in TableContainer component and without touching MyDataGrid component.

**TableContainer.js**

```
export default function TableContainer({ title, sx, table, columns, children }) {
    const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = useState({items: []});

    const filterModelChange = (model, details) => {
        setFilterModel(model);
    };

    const newProp = {
        filterModel,
        onFilterModelChange: filterModelChange
    };

    const newChildren = cloneElement(children, newProp, null);

    const clearSearch = () => {
        setFilterModel({items: []});
    };


    return (
        <Box sx={{ height: '100%', borderRadius: '5px', border: '1px solid gray', boxShadow: '0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)', overflow: 'hidden', ...sx }} >
            <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" sx={{ backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white', padding: '10px' }} >
                <Box  >{title} </Box>
                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row"  >
                    <Box  > <Iconify icon="codicon:filter-filled" sx={{}} onClick={clearSearch} />X</Box>
                </Stack>
            </Stack>
            <Box sx={{ height: 'calc(100% - 44px)' }}>
                {newChildren}
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}
```